# Grails 2.0 unit testing issue with namedQuery in a domain class hierarchy

Tags: grails

Grails 2.0-
I am getting "property(subdomain1property) not found on BaseDomain" error when unit testing a controller that uses a named query. The application runs fine and returns correct results but unit test fails.

```
class BaseDomain {
    static namedQueries = {
        listDuplicates {instance ->
           if(instance instanceof SubDomain1) {
            eq('subdomain1property', instance.subdomain1property)
           }
        }
    }
}

class SubDomain1 extends BaseDomain {
  String subdomain1property
}
```

Unit Test for controller has

```
@Mock([BaseDomain, SubDomain1])
```

The controller has this line

```
BaseDomain.listDuplicates(instance)
```

Comment: You are trying to use the subclass property in the super class. BaseDomain don't have access to that. Why you not created this namedQuery in the SubDomain1?

Comment: I have SubDomain1, SubDomain2, SubDomain3 sub classes extending from BaseDomain. I do not want to repeat this query for each sub class. There are other properties common to all sub classes in this query which is not listed in the question for sake of brevity. By the way the application runs fine and returns the correct result for SubDomain1, SubDomain2, SubDomain3. It is the unit test that fails. I am thinking there must be some mocking that can fix my unit test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved the specific test case from Unit to Integration Test and that resolved the issue. I will update the answer if I find a way to mock polymorphism in my unit test.